# how to loop over a filed data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called **OrderCheckinoutLog** stores check-in and checkout actions on orders by some experts (In sql-server). The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderCheckInOutLogs
(
 Id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_OrderCheckInoutLog PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
 OrderId int NOT NULL,
 ExpertId int NOT NULL,
 OnCheckinoutStatus bit NOT NULL, /*New field to detect check-in by '0' and check-out status by '1'*/
 CheckinoutTime datetime2 (3) NOT NULL, /*New field to record check-in and check-out time according to field CheckinoutStatus*/
)
Go
```

Any checkout or check-in action is inserted as new record and this is specified by **OnCheckinoutStatus**. A service time is difference between checkout and check-in time. I want to calculate the average service time of each expert using a query.
Is there any way (without cursor)?

A query that lists expert Id and average of service time.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be more helpful.  That said, consider the window functions.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson **OnCheckinoutStatus** determines checkout or check-in

Comment: @Ryan Wilson For any checkout or check-in action we insert a row. A checkout or check-in action is specified with **OnCheckinoutStatus**, 0 for check-in and 1 for checkout.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahnejad That seems like alot of redundant data, you could save yourself the extra row and just add a checkout column.

Comment: @John Cappelletti The table became more simple! I want to get a list of records composed of **expertId** and **averageOfService** fileds.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson The problem has been declared as I said! Additional filed is not allowed.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahnejad Then you'll need to use a combination of `group by` and `avg` [avg-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [select-group-by-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Ryan Wilson I need loop over **CheckinoutTime** so that I get any pair of check-in and checkout time for any **specific order** and the difference, and then calculate the average.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahnejad You're thinking is linear ... stop that.   A set based approach is always better.   Again, sample data and desired results is best.  That eliminates assumptions and ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```sql
select expertId, AVG(processedTime)
FROM (
  select expertId, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, chkin.CheckinoutTime, 
  outAtime.chkoutTime)) processedTime, OrderID
  from OrderCheckInOutLogs chkin
  cross apply (
    select top 1 CheckinoutTime as chkoutTime
    from OrderCheckInOutLogs chkout
    where chkout.expertId = chkin.expertid
    and chkout.orderId = chkin.OrderId
    and chkout.OnCheckinoutStatus = 1 --checkout
    and chkout.CheckinoutTime >= chkin.CheckinoutTime
    order by CheckinoutTime
  ) outaTime
  where chkin.OnCheckinoutStatus = 0 -- checkin
  group by expertId, OrderId
) x
GROUP BY expertId
```

We gather all checkins, and then for each one, get the first checkout that happens after the checkin. I do this per OrderId, this allows multiple checkins to be counted in. I also firstly summarize per Order, so that multiple order checkin doesn't get skewered when doing average.

Finally i average the summarized processedTime per order to get total average time.

You probably do well to create an index on OnCheckinoutStatus, ExpertId, OrderId on your table.